# PrimeFaces DataTable which is inside OverlayPanel stops working when OverlayPanel is used inside Dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Here is my scenario. **Room** Object have **ManyToOne** relationship with **Tax** Object. There are two pages for Room, **Create New** and **List All**.

At Create New Page, there is Tax Field. I use **OverlayPanel + DataTable + SelectEvent** to assign Tax Object instead of using AutoComplete or SelectOneMenu. Everything works great at this page.

At List All Page, I use Pop-up Dialog to edit the desired record. **OverlayPanel + DataTable** not working anymore because OverlayPanel is inside the Dialog. **SelectEvent** still calls Tax Setter Method but value is null.

I use PrimeFaces 3.5 and looking for solutions that will work with PrimeFaces 3.5 only. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think OverlayPanel (DataTable inside) is not compatible with Dialog. Using Dialog again instead of OverlayPanel solved the problem. Dialog inside Dialog works fine. I have to add `appendToBody="true"` attribute to child Dialog because UI is blocked. I use PrimeFaces 3.5 and works for me.

Comment: Please don't 'think' make sure ;-)... And since you did not post any code, it is very hard to draw conclusions. _"I think OverlayPanel is not compatible with Dialog"_ This is not true and keep in mind that you are using an **old** version.. And _" Dialog inside Dialog works fine. Make sure child dialog should have appendToBody="true" attribute."_ is not true either... Totally depends on your usecase

Comment: Yes. My answer really depends on my use case. I won't use latest version. I've to use only 3.5 for many reasons. I'm just sharing my solution. DataTable is inside OverlayPanel. It's ok. When OverlayPanel is moved into Dialog, DataTable isn't working anymore. You can find similar questions but no solutions. So I use Dialog instead of OverlayPanel. DataTable works again. If I don't add appendToBody="true", I can't even click it. May be "not true" for you. But it solved my problem. :-)

Comment: But since you did not post any code, it is hard to know what **your** usecase is so others can hardly learn or  see if this 'workaround' is valid for them to or that they have another problem